# discord.py creating and appending lists?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, new-operator

I am trying to make a script for a discord bot, where i can use a command and enter the result into a json file.

e.g !add_ally BriansCrew

With BriansCrew being added to the following JSON file

```
{
  "allies_and_enemies": {
    "allies": [],
    "enemies": []

    }

}
```

My code is....

```
allies_and_enemies = {'allies': [], 'enemies': []}


def add_ally(ally_name):
    allies_and_enemies['allies'].append( ally_name )


def add_enemy(enemy_name):
    allies_and_enemies['enemy'].append( enemy_name )


@bot.command()
async def add_ally(ctx, *, args):
    ctx.message.content = "".join(*args)
    allies_and_enemies = ctx.message.content

    with open("ally.json") as f:
        ally = json.load(f)

    ally = allies_and_enemies["allies"].append(ally_name)

    with open( 'ally.json', 'w' ) as f:
        json.dump(ally, f )
```

I am a begginer, i'd really appreciate some explantion if possible

REgards,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic python script that will do this. You can create a json file and ready from it and overwrite the new data every time.

```
@bot.command()
async def add_ally(ctx, *args):
    with open('ally.json', 'r') as f:
        lines = json.loads(f.read())

    for ally in args:
        lines['allies_and_enemies']['allies'].append(ally)

    with open('ally.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(lines))
```